# Change order element's fadeIn based on their ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a really quick [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t2xpwgbk/) to show my current problem, that I currently do not know how to fix without changing too much of the code.

Currently the problem is that the pictures fade in from left to right according to the order it is displayed in the HTML body. How can I make the images fade in according to the order of the array list and not the way they are currently fading in without changing too much code? I hope this makes sense.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    function scaledTimeout(i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(fadelen[i]).fadeIn(1000);
         }, 1000 * i);
     };

     var elem = document.querySelectorAll("#fade0, #fade1, #fade2, #fade3, #fade4");
     var fadelen = jQuery.makeArray(elem);
     for(i = 0; i < fadelen.length; i++) {
        scaledTimeout([i]);
     };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://shushi168.com/data/out/193/37281782-random-image.png">
    <img id="fade0" style="height:50px;width:50px;display:none;" alt="Random Pic" src="http://shushi168.com/data/out/193/37281782-random-image.png">
</a>
<a href="http://shushi168.com/data/out/193/37281782-random-image.png">
    <img id="fade2" style="height:50px;width:50px;display:none;" alt="Random Pic" src="http://shushi168.com/data/out/193/37281782-random-image.png">
</a>
<a href="http://shushi168.com/data/out/193/37281782-random-image.png">
    <img id="fade1" style="height:50px;width:50px;display:none;" alt="Random Pic" src="http://shushi168.com/data/out/193/37281782-random-image.png">
</a>
<a href="http://shushi168.com/data/out/193/37281782-random-image.png">
    <img id="fade4" style="height:50px;width:50px;display:none;" alt="Random Pic" src="http://shushi168.com/data/out/193/37281782-random-image.png">
</a>
<a href="http://shushi168.com/data/out/193/37281782-random-image.png">
    <img id="fade3" style="height:50px;width:50px;display:none;" alt="Random Pic" src="http://shushi168.com/data/out/193/37281782-random-image.png">
</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

**querySelectorAll collects the elements not according to their order in the function, but according to their order in the DOM.**

---

Here is working code, where you collect elements according to the order in the array:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var selectors = "#fade0,#fade1,#fade2,#fade3,#fade4".split(',');

  function scaledTimeout(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(selectors[i]).fadeIn(1000);
    }, 1000*i);
  };

  for(i = 0; i < selectors.length; i++) {
    scaledTimeout([i]);
  };
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lustoykov/5t8ypfbj/2/)

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to make sure that your elements are sorted the way you wnat. I added an example of `sort` based on the `id` of the elements.
2. Instead of `display: none` i used the `opacity` option (to make sure the elements takes place on the screen).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    function scaledTimeout(i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(fadelen[i]).fadeTo(1000, 1);
         }, 1000 * i);
     };

     var elem = $("#fade0, #fade1, #fade2, #fade3, #fade4");
    
     var fadelen = jQuery.makeArray(elem).sort(function(a, b) {
       return $(a).attr('id') > $(b).attr('id');
     });
  debugger;
     for(i = 0; i < fadelen.length; i++) {
        scaledTimeout([i]);
     };
});
```

```css
a img {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://shushi168.com/data/out/193/37281782-random-image.png">
    <img id="fade0" style="height:50px;width:50px;" alt="Random Pic" src="http://shushi168.com/data/out/193/37281782-random-image.png">
</a>
<a href="http://shushi168.com/data/out/193/37281782-random-image.png">
    <img id="fade2" style="height:50px;width:50px;" alt="Random Pic" src="http://shushi168.com/data/out/193/37281782-random-image.png">
</a>
<a href="http://shushi168.com/data/out/193/37281782-random-image.png">
    <img id="fade1" style="height:50px;width:50px;" alt="Random Pic" src="http://shushi168.com/data/out/193/37281782-random-image.png">
</a>
<a href="http://shushi168.com/data/out/193/37281782-random-image.png">
    <img id="fade4" style="height:50px;width:50px;" alt="Random Pic" src="http://shushi168.com/data/out/193/37281782-random-image.png">
</a>
<a href="http://shushi168.com/data/out/193/37281782-random-image.png">
    <img id="fade3" style="height:50px;width:50px;" alt="Random Pic" src="http://shushi168.com/data/out/193/37281782-random-image.png">
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd be better of by just getting the number from the ID, and just adding the delay based on that

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function scaledTimeout(el, i){
        $(el).delay(1000*i).fadeIn(1000);
    };

    $('[id^=fade]').each(function() {
        scaledTimeout(this, this.id.replace(/\D/g,''));
    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    function scaledTimeout(el, i){
        $(el).delay(1000*i).fadeTo(1000, 1);
    };
    
    $('[id^=fade]').each(function() {
     scaledTimeout(this, this.id.replace(/\D/g,''));
    });
});
```

```css
img {opacity : 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<a href="http://shushi168.com/data/out/193/37281782-random-image.png">
  <img id="fade0" style="height:50px;width:50px;" alt="Random Pic"     src="http://shushi168.com/data/out/193/37281782-random-image.png">
</a>
<a href="http://shushi168.com/data/out/193/37281782-random-image.png">
  <img id="fade2" style="height:50px;width:50px;" alt="Random Pic"     src="http://shushi168.com/data/out/193/37281782-random-image.png">
</a>
<a href="http://shushi168.com/data/out/193/37281782-random-image.png">
  <img id="fade1" style="height:50px;width:50px;" alt="Random Pic"     src="http://shushi168.com/data/out/193/37281782-random-image.png">
</a>
<a href="http://shushi168.com/data/out/193/37281782-random-image.png">
  <img id="fade4" style="height:50px;width:50px;" alt="Random Pic"     src="http://shushi168.com/data/out/193/37281782-random-image.png">
</a>
<a href="http://shushi168.com/data/out/193/37281782-random-image.png">
  <img id="fade3" style="height:50px;width:50px;" alt="Random Pic"     src="http://shushi168.com/data/out/193/37281782-random-image.png">
</a>
</body>
```

Comment: The function could then be named `scaledDelay` for clarity. This is a great solution, it provides scalability, eliminating the need to add a new id to the array everytime a new image element is added to the markup.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working fiddle of what I believe you are looking for.

I first changed `display:none` to `opacity:0` so that the image do not pop in weird when loading them out of order, I then changed the elements to load by their `id` and their number appended to them.

I then changed the `fadeIn` method to `animate` so that it would work with opacity.

```
$("#fade"+i).animate({
    opacity: 1
  },400);
```

### Working Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/qb2j8w3m/